# Swift Module is compiled in version 4.2.1 instead of 5.0.1

Tags: ios, swift, module

I have a Swift Module that was fully migrated to Swift 5 using XCode version 10.2.1. When I 'distribute' the Module internally, I have no issues when integrating. When I distribute (using XCode's Organizer) the Module to another developer, they see the following error:

```
Module compiled with Swift 4.2.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0.1
```

My internal applications all use Swift 5 as the build language. My XCode command line tools are version 10.2.1.

The other developer is also using Swift 5 with XCode 10.2.1.

What do I need to do to make my Module compile appropriately?

Comment: Your Xcode Command Line Tools are 10.2.1, what about Xcode itself?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, this happens because the swift version of the module is not set correctly.

Before building the module, check the swift version of the module in `Build Settings/Swift Language Version`.

Comment: Unfortunately, all are set to Swift 5

Comment: that's really weird. Will you try delete derived data and build from clean again?

Comment: Yup. Even went so far as to many setup Toolchains and switch to Swift 4.2.1 and back to Swift 5.

Answer (score 0):

How is your module imported into your Xcode project? Are you using Carthage or Pod by any chance? If so, make sure your Terminal is pointing to the right XCode version prior to importing and installing your package locally via carthage or pod install.

1. Open a Terminal and check the selected XCode version:

> **/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version**

2. If this is not the same version of XCode, make sure to point to the your current XCode app binary

> **sudo xcode-select -switch PATH_TO_YOUR_XCODE.APP**

3. Import your package via carthage/pod, go back to your project in xcode, clean and build.

Comment: It is not imported via Pod or Carthage. The module is compiled to a framework and added to the project.